# Some time geoserver return wms file instead of image

Tags: openlayers, geoserver

I have setup a geoserver with openlayers, and I found some errors getting some tiles from wms in geoserver;
for some tiles I get response as application/octet-stream (and the browser show a save dialog) instead of png image specified in getmap parameters.
Here is image captured for more details.

Thanks lot for your help

[image]

Comment: Save the file, checks if it contains an XML exception.

That said, the information you provide here is less than minimal, no version, no info on the data, etc...
It is difficult to be of any help.

Simone.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I am half-year late, but maybe could help with my answer.

Usually, when you make a request to Geoserver, as @simogeo said, you have to define some parameters which usually geoserver requests as minimum parameters. These parameters could be: service, version, srs, request, layers, boundingbox, width, height and/or format.

So the URL request is something like the following one (<> tags depend on each one):

```
http://<IPaddress>/geoserver/<workspace>/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=<workspace>:<layername>&styles=&bbox=23.975,68.018,24.126,68.074&width=512&height=512&srs=CRS:84&format=image%2Fjpeg
```

In your case, looking for what you said, it seems that **format** parameter by default is octet-stream. If you **change that parameter to other format** such as the one in my example (image JPEG) you will receive a JPEG image back from the server.
If still there are errors, as @simogeo said, your server is returning errors (which will show them in a XML) and you will need to define better your request!

Hope not to be enough late my answer ;)